# postgresql returns incorrect date format

Tags: postgresql, date, knex.js

I am building an app using node.js with postgresql db and knex ORM. I have a column type `date`. I uploaded date data in the format YYYY-MM-DD (2016/05/12). When I view the data in pgAdmin, the data correctly shows as 2016/05/12. However, when I retrieve the data, it displays in the format:

`Wed May 11 2016 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)`

Does anyone know why this might be happening? Here's my query:

```
knex('projects').where({
    report_id: req.params.id
}).then(function(data) {
    console.log(data[0].created_at); //returns Wed May 11 2016 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)
    res.send(data);
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log('error: ' + error);
    res.sendStatus(500);
});
```

The query returns:

`Wed May 11 2016 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)` - which is off by a day adds additional information that i did not originally input into the database.

Does anyone know what might be going on?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know knex.js, but it seems that something on the client side is converting the date to something of its own choosing. Look there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `date` data type in javascript. Your `date` sql data type is being casted as a `datetime` javascript data type, and that's why timezone information is being appended.

To fix it, try having the call to the database return the field as `varchar`, (ie something like `var data = db.query('select date::varchar from table',conn)` then javascript will think it's `string`, and thus data integrity of the field is preserved.